# Extracting a string, according to a pattern, in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

In bash, suppose that I have a string `strname`:

```
strname="ph7go04325r"
```

I would like to extract the characters between the *first* `"3"` character and the *last* `"r"` character in `strname`, saving the result in a string `strresult`.  In the example above, the resulting `strresult` would be:

```
strresult="25"
```

The first `"3"` character is *not* necessarily at string position 8 in `strname`; likewise, the last `"r"` is *not* necessarily at string position 11.  Thus, both of the following strings `strname` should yield `strresult="25"`:

```
strname="ph11go04325raa"
strname="325r"
strname="rgo04325raa"
```

Also, `strname=ph12go04330raa"` should yield `strresult="30"`.

I am new to bash scripting, and I don't know where to begin to do string pattern matching like this.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a regex in bash (3.0 or above) to accomplish this:

```
if [[ $strname =~ 3(.+)r ]]; then
    strresult=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
    echo "unable to parse string $strname"
fi
```

In bash, capture groups from a regex are placed in the special array `BASH_REMATCH`. Element 0 contains the entire match, and 1 contains the the match for the first capture group.

Answer (score 10):

In standard `sh` syntax (so would work with any version of `bash` or any other POSIX compliant shell), you would do:

```
case $strname in
  (*3*r*) 
    strresult=${strname#*3}
    strresult=${strresult%r*};;
  (*)
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "Unable to parse string $strname"
esac
```

See also the old `expr` solution which will even work on 35 year old Unices:

```
expr "x$strname" : 'x[^3]*3\(.*\)r'
```

The old *quirk* with `expr` is that if the match fails you get a non-zero exit status (fine), but you also get a non-zero exit status if the returned strings resolves to 0 (like with `strname=zz300rzz`).

Comment: I think your phrasing incorrectly implies that this can *only* be done with older versions of bash. The parameter expansion is, of course, still a fine approach in modern shells.

Comment: @kojiro, I see what you mean. The initial formulation was to follow-up on Jordan's answer. I've updated my answer.